# C# to store data into MS-Access database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I need to write C# code to insert data into an MS-Access database. The program adds it but if I close the application the database resets. 
database is in the debug x86 folder

Here is my code for adding data

```
provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"; 

applicatiePad = Application.ExecutablePath.Substring(0, Application.ExecutablePath.LastIndexOf("\\"));
pad = "Data Source=" + applicatiePad + "/Geluidsfragmentendb.accdb";
connectionString = provider + ";" + pad;

connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

...

public bool VoegToe(int geluidsfragmentnr,
    string Titel,
    string bestandsnaam,
    int min,
    int sec)
{
    string time = min + ":" + sec;

    DateTime tijd = Convert.ToDateTime(time);

    String voegGfToe = "INSERT INTO Geluidsfragment (GeluidsfragmentID, Titel, bestandsnaam, tijdsduur) VALUES (" + geluidsfragmentnr + ",'" + Titel + "'" + ",'"+ bestandsnaam + "','" + tijd + "')";

    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(voegGfToe, connection);

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return true;
    }
    catch ( Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use parameters ... and is your `mdb` or `accdb` file included as `Build Action: Content`? Because it would get copied to the output directory each time. Overwriting whatever was there beforehand.

Comment: `but if i close the apllication the database resets.` : where does the database reside?

Comment: Close the command before closing the connection in final.

Comment: Some side remark; Use Path.Combine for concatanating directory paths & files, not string manipulation.

Comment: command.Close gets an error

Comment: Put it after `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` and don't forget the `();` at the end.